# Edit array within a collection Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection of arrays and need to edit automatically some of the values within some of the arrays. However, some of them are so large that copying the array to a new variable, deleting the collection item, editing the copy, and then putting it back into the collection is not only inelegant but also very slow at best. Does anyone know of any other ways to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

I should have specified that the collection exists within a custom class and so the array variables are not directly accessible. An illustration of my problem:

```
Sub illustration()

Dim coll As New Collection
Dim arr As Variant
ReDim arr(0 To 1)
arr(0) = "hello"
arr(1) = "world"
coll.Add arr

coll(1)(0) = "goodbye"

Debug.Print Join(arr)
Debug.Print Join(coll(1))

slowMethod coll, 1

Debug.Print Join(arr)
Debug.Print Join(coll(1))

End Sub

Sub slowMethod(ByRef edit_coll As Collection, index As Integer)

Dim return_arr As Variant
return_arr = edit_coll(index) '<--this will take up a lot of memory if the array has, say, 300,000 records

edit_coll.Remove index

return_arr(LBound(return_arr)) = "goodbye"

edit_coll.Add return_arr

End Sub
```

The desired output "goodbye world" will only occur (to my knowledge) using the method I don't want to use.

Comment: You dont need to copy the `array` if all what you want is to change the `values`.

Comment: @A.S.H See edit. I hope I've made myself clearer.

Comment: So your custom class has only methods that return or set entire arrays? And you dont own its code I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that [collections are read-only](http://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/#Collections_Vs_Arrays), so there is no solution of the type I was looking for. I chose to rethink the problem instead.